# jQuery image src selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I’m trying to get a jQuery selector to return all the images that don’t have a certain src.

```
$('img[src!="/img/none.png"]')
```

These images are already transparent so, for performance sake I'm trying to exclude them from the ones that I fade in/out. But the query still returns the images with src = /img/none.png

If however I do

```
$('img[src="/img/none.png"]')
```

It will return only the images with src = /img/none.png. So it seems like the attribute not equal selector is broken?

Relevant documentation
http://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try

```
$('img:not([src="/img/none.png"])');
```

If that doesn't work, try

```
$('img:not([src$="/img/none.png"])');
```

depending on what browser you're in, the src isn't interpreted as what you set, it's interpreted as the absolute URI, so your browser thinks it's `http://www.yoursite.com/img/none.png`.  I'm not sure how jQuery is reading the src so it may be picking up the absolute URI.

Comment: If the last statement was the cause, then jQuery would return all images because they are not equal to whatever one specifies...

Comment: @JCOC — The second snippet uses the [attribute-ends-with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/), so would read "images which do not end with '/img/none.png'".

Comment: @Ben Blank - He meant that the 2nd example that the OP posted wouldn't work, he's correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [:not selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/).

```
$('img:not([src="/img/none.png"])')
```

If you're using a mixture of relative or absolute paths for the image you might want to use the "[attribute ends with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/)" selector as mentioned in another answer.

```
$('img:not([src$="/img/none.png"])')
```